# Can I defend with a card from my hand and a defense reaction against an attack with "Dominate"?

Tags: flesh-and-blood

My opponent played an attack with Dominate against me. I defended with a card from my hand. Now, it's time to play defense reactions. Can I play one and add its defense stat to the chain? If yes, why? Dominate says "you can't defend with more than one card from your hand".